# Check if a value is present in a record or not?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell

Suppose I have a record named #parameters, and I am accessing it from outside and I do not know if all the keys inside it have a value stored with it.

Suppose there is a key in my record named Index. How can I check if the value for Index is present in my record or not? And how do I put it in a case statement like:

```
Index = find from the record  
or else put it as 100.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am accessing it from outside and I do not know if all the keys
> inside it have a value stored with it.

All fields in a record have a value.  If a default value for a field is not specified in the record definition, then erlang uses the atom `undefined` for the default value.  For instance:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

-record(pattern, {a, b=0, c}).

go() ->
    #pattern{a=1}.
```

In the shell,

```
1> c(a).
a.erl:2:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
%    2| -compile(export_all).
%     |  ^
{ok,a}

2> rr(a).
[pattern]

3> a:go().
#pattern{a = 1,b = 0,c = undefined}
```

> Suppose there is a key in my record named Index; how can I check if
> the value for Index is present in my record or not?

Once again, there will always be a value for the `index` key.  Here's an example that demonstrates how to do one thing if `index` has the value `undefined` and do something else if `index` has some other value.

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

-record(pattern, {a, b=0, index}).

go() ->
    Pattern1 = #pattern{a=1},
    check_index(Pattern1),
    Pattern2 = #pattern{a=1, index=10},
    check_index(Pattern2).

check_index(#pattern{index=undefined}) ->
    io:format("index key is undefined~n");
check_index(#pattern{index=Number}) ->
    io:format("index key is ~w~n", [Number]).
```

In the shell:

```
1> c(a).  
a.erl:2:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
%    2| -compile(export_all).
%     |  ^
{ok,a}

2> rr(a). 
[pattern]

3> a:go().
index key is undefined
index key is 10
ok
```

You could also turn the `check_index()` function into a boolean function that returns true or false.